# Android Jetpack Navigation Pass Lambda/Delegate between Fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx, android-jetpack

I would like to pass a lambda from fragment A to fragment B when A transitions to B via a `findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_a_to_b)`. The use case is B helps pick an item out to display on screen A.

Something like:

```
// In A
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_a_to_b, configBlock: { fragmentB ->
    fragmentB.itemSelectedCallback = this::itemSelected
})
```

I recognize this pattern doesn't quite fit with what Google is pushing (I assume they want shared observed view models with fragments not communicating between each other) but I am not looking to transition to that architecture style yet.

Comment: If you're not looking to translate to that model, you may want to rethink using the navigation library at all.

Comment: Lambdas don't survive configuration changes or process death, so this style of callback is lossy in many real cases.

Answer (score 1):

This is not yet possible, however, there is an [existing feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79672220) for being able to navigate for a result, which would let you get this type of functionality.